# TypeError: undefined is not a function - Angularjs + JQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js and JQuery, and i keep getting the following error message when clicking on input fields:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at bg.$setTouched (angular.js:20798)
at l.$get.l.$eval (angular.js:16131)
at l.$get.l.$apply (angular.js:16159)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:20798)
at HTMLInputElement.m.event.dispatch (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
at HTMLInputElement.m.event.add.r.handle (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)angular.js:12016 (anonymous function)angular.js:8555 $getangular.js:16163 $get.l.$applyangular.js:20798 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 m.event.dispatchjquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 m.event.add.r.handle
```

My input fields look somthing like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city"
            placeholder="city" ng-model="pc.newProperty.city">
</div>
```

Everything seems to work fine but I want to get rid of these error messages, but I can't figure out what is causing them, any ideas?

Comment: angular version, any plugins for angular/jquery?

Comment: angular version: 1.3.15, plugins: jquery.easing, query.animate-enhanced, jquery.superslides, angular-ui-router, angular-animate 1.2.0-rc.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because a different versions of your angular-animate and angular javascripts files.